# localhost is always responding with "Connection refused: localhost:80"

Tags: network, osx-server, apache

I've been working with the integrated webserver of OS X El Capitan for a while now.
I am developing a website project and thus, this was the perfect solution for me.
I was starting the local server using `php -S localhost:8088 -t .` in the specific directory containing the website data (index.php etc.).
Everything was working fine until I refreshed the page one day and it suddenly printed: `Connection refused: localhost:8088`. There were no changes made to any config files or anything else.
It doesn't matter which port I am using, it always refuses the connection. Sending a request to `127.0.0.1` in my browser tells me `It works!`. But, once I am starting the server and calling `127.0.0.1:8088`, my browser responds with its default page displaying that the connection has been refused, as if I did not start/run the server.

The first thing I did was checking whether the Apache config is broken.
But, `apachectl configtest` printed `Syntax OK`.

When I tried to ping `localhost`, I encountered a 100% package loss, so at first I thought that the bug may be located inside the hosts file.
`cat /etc/hosts/` printed out the following:

```
##
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

Looks appropriate, doesn't it?
So, I checked my firewall options and discovered that I had "Stealth mode" activated. Unchecking it resulted in having the ICMP-packages finding their way correctly and there was no package loss any longer.

The thing is that I don't know why this problem suddenly occured and how I am able to fix it. I already restored all Apache config files to the originals, but that didn't solve it neither.
It seems to be listening on that port, but I can't access the server as it always refuses the connection.
Even if the server is not started, accessing `localhost` prints `Connection refused: localhost:80`. I don't know where the error could be located.
Apache's error log didn't show anything conspicious neither.

`sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP | grep LISTEN` showed that `httpd` is using IPv6 only, so that should work.

If you need any more (config) files, just request them.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that the problem occured only in Opera, not Safari or any other browser. I found out that I had Opera Turbo enabled which would of course let me access my own `localhost` correctly.